# How to measure clustering in time duration?

Tags: clustering

I wish to measure clustering in the duration between stock trading. For example, a trade occurs at 1:59:19 and the next trade follows at 1:59:23 - the inter-trade duration is 4 seconds. I have roughly 50,000 trades per day for a particular stock. I was told that I can square the inter-trade duration in order to capture clustering in trades. Is this correct? What if I have a lot of trades that occur at the same time? Hence, inter-trade duration is 0 seconds. Can this have an impact on my clustering measure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's straightforward to compute, so obviously, you can *do* it.

But I don't know a reason *why* you should take the squared delays. Is $s^2$ a sensible score here? To me this sounds like a *heuristic*.

**Define "correct".** I don't see any notion of correctness involved here. It may *work* for some, it may *not work* for others. It may be *sensible* for some use case, or it might not. This is more of a personal preference than a mathematical truth.

Answer (score 2):

When measuring clustering in time I don't think squared distance in time makes much sense at all. A rate in terms of events per unit time seems more reasonable to me.  Periods with high rates are the event cluster intervals.